# "Call to implicitly deleted default constructor of "error

Tags: c++, debugging, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

I keep getting three errors that all relate to "Call to implicitly deleted default constructor of ____. Would anyone happen to know why this is?

/Users/vivekreddy/Desktop/Vivek/School/Spring 2016/CS32/project 3/project 3/Player.cpp:114:18: Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'BadPlayerImpl'

```
#include "provided.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class HumanPlayerImpl:public Player
{
  public:
    virtual bool isInteractive() const { return true;};
    int chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color);

};

class BadPlayerImpl: public Player
{
  public:
    int chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color);
};

class SmartPlayerImpl: public Player
{
  public:
    virtual bool isInteractive() const { return true;};
    int chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color);
};




//implementations


//put virtual in front of implementations only or declarations here as well?


int HumanPlayerImpl::chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color)  //goal is to get N in a row, return the column necessary to put the checker so we could do that.  otherwise return -1.  can make the column be arbitrary
{
    //algorithm is inputting N so maybe don't need this check?
    if (N>s.cols()||N<=0) {
        cout<<"Enter a number within the valid range of columns you specified";
        return -1;
    }

    if(s.numberEmpty()==0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int columnnum;
    while (columnnum<=s.cols()||columnnum<=0) {
        cout<<"Enter column number of your move";
        cin>>columnnum;
        if (columnnum<=s.cols()) {
            return columnnum;
        }
        cout<<"Column number not valid ";
    }
    return -1; //OK?
}

int BadPlayerImpl::chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color)
{
    if ((N>=s.cols()&&N>=s.levels())||N<=0) { //make sure this works
        cout<<"Enter a number within the valid range of columns you specified";
        return -1;
    }
    for (int j=0; j<s.cols();j++) {
        if (s.checkerAt(j,0)==VACANT) { 
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1; //see if this OK
}

int SmartPlayerImpl::chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color)
{
    return -1;  //  This is not always correct; it's just here to compile
}

//******************** Player derived class functions *************************

// These functions simply delegate to the Impl classes' functions.
// You probably don't want to change any of this code.

HumanPlayer::HumanPlayer(string nm)
 : Player(nm)
{
    m_impl = new HumanPlayerImpl;  //error is here
}

HumanPlayer::~HumanPlayer()
{
    delete m_impl;
}

int HumanPlayer::chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color)
{
    return m_impl->chooseMove(s, N, color);
}

BadPlayer::BadPlayer(string nm)
 : Player(nm)
{
    m_impl = new BadPlayerImpl;  //error is here 
}

BadPlayer::~BadPlayer()
{
    delete m_impl;
}

int BadPlayer::chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color)
{
    return m_impl->chooseMove(s, N, color);
}

SmartPlayer::SmartPlayer(string nm)
 : Player(nm)
{
    m_impl = new SmartPlayerImpl;  //error is here 
}

SmartPlayer::~SmartPlayer()
{
    delete m_impl;
}

int SmartPlayer::chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color)
{
    return m_impl->chooseMove(s, N, color);
}
```

Below is my declaration of the class Player which is the base class:

```
class Player
{
  public:
    Player(std::string nm) : m_name(nm) {}
    virtual ~Player() {};
    std::string name() const { return m_name; };
    virtual bool isInteractive() const { return false; }
    virtual int chooseMove(const Scaffold& s, int N, int color) = 0;
      // We prevent any kind of Player object from being copied or assigned by
      // making the copy constructor and assignment operator unavailable in
      // the base class (and thus in any derived class).
    Player(const Player& other) = delete;
    Player& operator=(const Player& other) = delete;
  private:
    std::string m_name;
};
```

Comment: based on what you've posted here, `m_impl` could be a private member of `Player`, with virtual `chooseMove` member, and `Player` has non-virtual one that calls the impl.  That would reduce a lot of the boilerplate junk

Comment: the `...PlayerImpl` classes should not derive from `Player`. You've got a tangled mess of class relationships here

Answer (score 4):

Because you declared a constructor in your base class, in particular `Player::Player(std::string nm)`, it's impossible for the compiler to provide an implicit default constructor for your child class as your parent class `Player` can't be default constructed in the first place.

Either provide a constructor in your child class or inherit the constructor of your base class (C++11). E.g:

```
BadPlayerImpl::BadPlayerImpl(std:string nm)
  : Player(nm)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: May I ask a question: For the lines marked as "//error is here" (constructors of the sub-classes), is he creating a memory leak? The constructor will return a newly created objects, and he's creating a new one to be assigned to m_impl.So when the destructor is called, only m_impl is deleted, but not the original object?

Comment: @ABuckau Sorry I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. The destructor will always clean up any members in reversed order of initialization after it's body have ran (in case an explicit destructor is provided). While the use of raw pointers is discouraged (`std::unique_ptr` would be better here), this code works correctly in regard to memory.

Comment: By using 'new' inside his constructor, won't there be 2 objects created..and the destructor only cleans up m_impl?

Comment: @ABuckau He's creating a `PlayerImpl` object, assigns it to `m_impl` and cleans it up in his destructor. Wheres the issue?

Comment: Do all constructors contain a call to new? Isn't the constructor creating an object, and new is creating a 2nd. (?) Then the destructor only deletes the 2nd. I'll write up a test and check.

Comment: @ABuckau `new` allocates memory on the heap, then initializes the object by calling the constructor and finally returns the pointer to the freshly created object. Notice that he has `BadPlayer` class and a `BadPlayerImpl` class.

Comment: @ABuckau a constructor initializes an object after storage has already been obtained

Comment: @M.M I was confused about destruction, not construction..unless you're being subtle; I don't understand your point. I didn't think objects were (could possibly be) initialized at {nowhere}. edit: I believe Sebastian answered my question in his first reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because somewhere in your code you are copy-constructing, or assigning to, an instance of `BadPlayerImpl`, and you explicitly deleted the copy constructor and the assignment operator of its superclass.

Comment: more likely, attempt to default-construct an instance of `BadPlayerImpl` which has no default constructor (because its base class didn't)

Answer (score 0):

A default constructor is normally automatically created for a class, but there are rules about when it is not created (like when you create another constructor). Where you have "//error is here" you're calling the default constructor of a Sub-Class which will call the (in this case, non-existent) default constructor of the Base-Class.